# Resizing 4000+ images using a grunt plugin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, image-resizing

I am trying to resize 4000 images using node.js, grunt, and a grunt plugin. Currently I am using `grunt-imagemagick` though I get similar errors no matter what I use.

Can anyone either shed some light on the error or else recommend a grunt plugin that will work out of the box on OSX for moderately largish directories of images ?

- OS: OSX 10.9
- node: v0.8.16
- grunt: v0.4.1
- grunt-imagemagick: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-imagemagick

Here's the output from console when running the grunt task with `--stack` option

```
$ grunt --stack imagemagick-resize

Running "imagemagick-resize:people" (imagemagick-resize) task
Beginning ImageMagick resizing process
resizing:../photos_src/organisms/Genus_Acanthostrongylophora^Species_ashmorica.jpg...
    ...
    ... (approx 170 files)
    ...
resizing:../photos_src/organisms/Genus_Chrysomelobia^species_lipsettae.jpg...
resizing:../photos_src/organisms/Genus_Chrysomelobia^species_vafer.jpg...
Warning: spawn EMFILE Use --force to continue.
Error: spawn EMFILE
    at errnoException (child_process.js:847:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:794:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:618:9)
    at exec2 (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/node_modules/node-imagemagick/lib/imagemagick.js:24:25)
    at Object.exports.convert (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/node_modules/node-imagemagick/lib/imagemagick.js:262:10)
    at resizeCall (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/node_modules/node-imagemagick/lib/imagemagick.js:267:22)
    at Object.exports.resize (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/node_modules/node-imagemagick/lib/imagemagick.js:282:10)
    at Object.ResizeCommand.init (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/tasks/imagemagick.js:112:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt-imagemagick/tasks/imagemagick.js:222:11)
    at Object.task.registerMultiTask.thisTask (/Users/user/Documents/projectName/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:258:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here may be answer on your question: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/788

> `EMFILE` means it is trying to open more file descriptors than your system allows. If you're on OSX, the default is 256 and really low. You can temporarily increase it on your session with `ulimit -n 10480` (assuming your own OSX).

Comment: running `ulimit -n 10480` didnt seem to work nor did `sudo ulimit -n 10480`. I am going to try and restart and see if this setting has taken effect, and that the grunt-imagemagick task runs to completion with the new suggested setting.

Comment: doesnt seem to have worked. at console when i run `$ ulimit -n` it still says `256`

Comment: One more try:http://superuser.com/questions/261023/how-to-change-default-ulimit-values-in-mac-os-x-10-6

Comment: not working for me. still getting EMFILE error. totally at a loss how i can resize these images using grunt !